# TMDB api how to search exact person

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api, themoviedb-api

Im trying to fetch information about a person(actor) from TMDB API. My request is

```
http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/person?query=Rose+Byrne&api_key=(apikey)
```

But this gives me all actors whose names are consist of "Rose Byrne".

```
     { 
        page: 1,
        results: [
            {
                  profile_path: "/fOQLAPDvqSDq4ktR7Xk8DIpzGdY.jpg",
                  adult: false,
                  id: 9827,
                  known_for: [],
                  name: "Rose Byrne",
                  popularity: 19.636456
            },
            {
                  profile_path: "/vXDTGWlBWX72fozu08wRSQY6Ok.jpg",
                  adult: false,
                  id: 206926,
                  known_for: [],
                  name: "Darcy Rose Byrnes",
                  popularity: 1.912625
           },
           {
                  profile_path: null,
                  adult: false,
                  id: 1215680,
                  known_for: [],
                  name: "Darcy Rose Byrnes",
                  popularity: 1
           }
           ],
        total_results: 3,
        total_pages: 1
    }
```

I need exact person "Rose Byrne". Is it possible ? How can I rearrange my request. Thank you.

Comment: I don't think that'd be possible. However, you can restrict the data you display by matching your search query with the name parameter of each of the results.